# Sikuli Windows Selenium Java Error: Fatal Error 110: loading: WinUtil.dll

Tags: java, windows, selenium-webdriver, sikuli

Error shown for running Sikuli script in Selenium WebDriver using Java

> [error] ResourceLoaderBasic: loadLib: Fatal Error 110: loading: WinUtil.dll
>   [error] ResourceLoaderBasic: loadLib: Since native library was found, it might be a problem with needed dependent libraries
>   D:\Snehal Gaidhane\Non-Project Work\Supportive Files\libs\WinUtil.dll: The specified procedure could not be found
>   [error] ResourceLoaderBasic: loadLib: Check, wether a valid Sikuli libs folder is in system path at runtime!
>   [error] Terminating SikuliX after a fatal error(110)! Sorry, but it makes no sense to continue!
>   If you do not have any idea about the error cause or solution, run again
>   with a Debug level of 3. You might paste the output to the Q&A board.

Comment: 110 = ERROR_OPEN_FAILED. Does that WinUtil.dll exist in the path it's looking at? Where did you get it from? Is it the right version? (I'm unsure why you'd get message "The specified procedure could not be found" if that's not the error code though.)

Comment: Yes, I am able to find the WinUtil.dll at mentioned path: D:\Snehal Gaidhane\Non-Project Work\Supportive Files\libs\WinUtil.dll

Comment: Then I'd guess it's a dependency problem: that version of the DLL depends on other DLLs or other versions of those DLLs that it can't find. (Which would explain "the specified procedure cannot be found")

Answer (score 1):

A WinUtil.dll is a Sikuli library file. ONLY ONE Sikuli libs folder should be on system path at runtime and this should be the one fitting to the running Sikuli (Sikuli internally tries to support this, if not hindered by the user).

Check, whether a valid Sikuli libs folder is in system path at runtime. Try deleting your libs folder, and then restart your own script. If this does not work, the Java / Sikuli path may not be configured correctly. Are you using 32-bit or 64-bit java? If 32 bit, please retry with 64 bit.

Also, you could try running your batch again with java option -Dsikuli.Debug=3 for a detailed output to get a hint on the problem.

The cause could be because the libraries referenced in WinUtil are not found, which is definitely a problem of system path at runtime.  In some cases, it turned out to be AWT.DLL. if your path has %JAVA_HOME%\bin, but not %JAVA_HOME%\jre\bin then the AWT.DLL could be missing.- which is where the dll is. You could use a dependency walker to find out the exact DLL not found by WinUtil.dll.

Please paste more debug logs by running with java option -Dsikuli.Debug=3 to get a detailed insight into the problem.

Comment: Tried by as suggested changing the path from %JAVA_HOME%\bin, to %JAVA_HOME%\jre\bin

Comment: how do i activate java option mentioned?